# How to use pointers in an union

Tags: c++, c

I want to put both 1-dimensional array pointer and 2-dimensional array pointer in a union, so I can access data either way. In the following program I would like to see the value `9` is printed out by both ways.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    union {
        int** array2D;
        int*  array1D;
    };
    A() {
        array2D = new int*[1];
        array2D[0] = new int[1];
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.array2D[0][0] = 9;
    cout << a.array2D[0][0] << endl;
    cout << a.array1D[0]    << endl;
    cout << a.array2D << endl;
    cout << a.array1D << endl;
}
```

The actual output:

```
9
146989080
0x8c2e008 //Pointer address of array2D
0x8c2e008 //Pointer address of array1D
```

The addresses are identical and by definition multidimensional arrays are stored in the same way as are one-dimensional arrays. I wonder why the two `cout`s print out different results? What did I miss?

EDIT:
Thanks to the answers below, I can see what I missed.
The fix for accessing data from array1D is:

`cout << *( (int*) a.array1D[0])    << endl;`

Comment: Your `array1D` is 'holding' the pointer to the first row of `array2D`, in case you weren't aware of that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep I wasn't aware of that :D
I thought locating array using `new` was the same to declaring a fixed-size array, that's what misled me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you are invoking *undefined-behavior*.

the standard says that you are only allowed to read from the member of a union that you last wrote t, reading `array2D` and `array1D` interchangeably is therefore not allowed (even though it often works in practice it is **not** recommended).

Second; using `array1D` you are trying to dereference and read the value at the address currently (*supposedly* because of *UB*) having been allocated for a `new int*[1]`, the value of `array2D[0][0]` is located one further step down the path.

---

To access the value you are expecting from `a.array1D` you will need something as the below (not recommended)

```
**reinterpret_cast<int**> (a.array1D);
```

Comment: Thanks, that `reinterpret_cast` is new to me. I used `*( (int*) a.array1D[0]` and it works fine, I hope it's safe to use even though I don't know why it is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate multidimensional array using `new`, the way you do it, you are actually allocating a number of arrays.
The first one is an array of pointers to array. Thus your `a.array1D[0]` contains actually pointer to pointer to array, and you are printing a value of the pointer.

I am pretty sure if you will do the following:

```
cout << (int*)a.array1D[0] << endl;
```

you will get the same as:

```
cout << a.array2D[0] << endl;
```

Comment: When you allocate a multidimensional array with `new` you are allocating one contiguous block: `int (*ar)[10] = new int[10][10];`. It is not intrinsically an array of pointers. The OP's code *is* an array of pointers, but it is *not* a multidimensional array in any way except syntax of usage.

Comment: +1 Thats actually one of the better descriptions of how a pointer array is laid out when using one to mimic a multi-dimensional array (and not too wordy either, bravo), and well-worded on how that relates to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

When you print out the value of `a.array2D` is points to the beginning of the array. Since you are using a union both `array1D` and `array2D` occupy the same space and will contain the same value.

When you access the pointer value in `a.array1D[0]` you are telling it to get the first element of `array1D`. Because you are using a `union` this also points to the first element of `array2D` which happens to be a pointer.